# How do I transfer an image from Digital Ocean hosting to a website? Golang

Tags: go, hosting, digital-ocean

I have uploaded a binary file to the DO hosting. This is a golang project where I can create flashcards in the admin area. The card contains a title and an image. Only the path to the image is saved in the database. However, the binary file on the server cannot contain these images in advance, they are added as needed. Therefore, I noticed that when saving the card, the picture is saved in a certain directory next to this binary file:

```
x@x-production:~$ ls
assets  migrations  web
```

web - project file;
assets - directory with pictures of the card;
For example, in assets, the path to the catalog cover image looks like this:

```
x@x-production:~/assets/static/img/catalog/2$ ls
1708864387803037959.webp
```

This picture really exists.

The question is, how do I transfer the path to it to the site? Because

```
x.ru/static/img/catalog/*/*.webp
```

or

```
x.ru/static/img/catalog/*/*.webp
```

does not work. Maybe it's because the binary file looks for these paths directly in its statics?
Do I really have to connect Spaces Object Storage?
I use Caddy for the proxy:

```
x.ru {
    reverse_proxy localhost:4000
}
```

I don't really understand it yet, but that's not how it works either (here I wanted to at least clearly get to the bottom of the picture):

```
x.ru {
    reverse_proxy localhost:4000

    root * /assets
    file_server

    route /static/img/catalog/2/1708864387803037959.webp {
        root * /assets/static/img/catalog/2
        file_server
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is in your hosting asset directory, isn't it already on the site?  I don't understand why you need to transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation, I realized that there is a "route" function that explicitly positions query execution. Before that, my proxy intercepted all requests

```
x.ru {
    route {
        encode gzip

        file_server /static/* browse {
            root /home/stm/assets
        }

        reverse_proxy * localhost:4000
    }
}
```